# Creating an R barplot with a subset of my dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, bar-chart, subset

I am trying to make a barplot in R with the following data frame and code below. However, when I do this, the year column also gets inserted into my graph. Is there a way to stop this from happening but still keep my graph sorted by the year?

```
 barplot(t(as.matrix(Number_Letter_Year_DF)), beside=TRUE, 
            xlab="Year", ylab="Number", 
            names.arg=c("2016","2017", "2018"),
            legend= c("A", "B","C","D","E","F"),  args.legend = list(title="Letter", x="topright", cex=.7))
            abline(h=0)



Year     A     B     C     D     E     F
2016 2547.150 2001.075 2493.925 1123.450 1876.625 1718.175
2017 2829.025 1808.025 2681.850 2633.425 3005.525 2542.550
2018 1776.175 1538.900 1614.675  845.225 1155.500 1029.325
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can remove the first column i.e. 'year' and change it to row names

```
barplot(t(`row.names<-`(as.matrix(Number_Letter_Year_DF[-1]), Number_Letter_Year_DF$Year)), beside=TRUE, 
         xlab="Year", ylab="Number", 
         names.arg=c("2016","2017", "2018"),
         legend= c("A", "B","C","D","E","F"),  args.legend = list(title="Letter", x="topright", cex=.7))
         abline(h=0)
```

[image]

#### data

```
Number_Letter_Year_DF <- structure(list(Year = 2016:2018, A = c(2547.15, 2829.025, 1776.175
), B = c(2001.075, 1808.025, 1538.9), C = c(2493.925, 2681.85, 
1614.675), D = c(1123.45, 2633.425, 845.225), E = c(1876.625, 
3005.525, 1155.5), F = c(1718.175, 2542.55, 1029.325)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have like 28 other variables I have to convert into this format... is there a way for me to get rid of the row names without having to individually type in all their respective values? Or is there a way for me to restructure all my groups? I used- Variable_Rotation_Year_DF<-dcast(DT, Year~Rotation, value.var = "Variable", fun.aggregate = mean, na.rm = TRUE, fill= NA)

Comment: @Phiefs3000. Do you have the objects names that start with `Smois_Rotation` or is it different names.  If you have more than 2 objects, place it in a list and do this once with `lapply` i.e. `lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = "^Smois_Rotation")); lapply(lst1, function(x) {x1 <- as.matrix(x[-1]); row.names(x1) <- x$year;  x1})`

Comment: @Phiefs3000 then you may need to change the pattern iin `ls` if these are only objects in the global env, use `ls()`